# Flutter unzip folder is empty (flutter_archive 4.2.0)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, unzip

In the following code I select a zip file with filePicker that is in the downloads folder of the device, I say that the extraction point will be the same folder but when I select the file and perform the extraction process, everything in the log looks perfect, but when I access the created directory it says that it is empty. I attach the code:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      final zip = File(result.files.single.path.toString());
      final unZip = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download");
      print(unZip.path.toString());
      print(zip);
      try{
        ZipFile.extractToDirectory(zipFile: zip, destinationDir: unZip);
      }catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
```

These are the permissions that I have assigned in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final unZip = Directory('${tempDir.path}/Download');
```

instead of this

```
final unZip = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download");
```

Comment: Your answer did not work for me, but it did help me to get the library that helps me extract the file, in the end the best option was to use these lines very similar to yours: 

final appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final unZip = Directory('${appDir?.path}/Proyectos');

Comment: Then how it solved Dishonored ? Also facing something like this